# ¿Cómo guardar el modo oscuro?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

este es el código funcional de JavaScript que tengo para que, mediante un botón, al hacer clic, el contneido cambie del "light mode" al "dark mode" y viceversa.

```
const theme_btn = document.querySelector('#btn-toggle');
//const body = document.querySelector("body");
//theme_btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
//body.classList.toggle('dark-mode')
//});
```

Sin embargo, he tratado de adaptarlo mediante localStorage para que al dar refresh en la página se guarde el modo oscuro, ¿Cómo puedo modificar este código? ¿Qué está mal?

```
function toggle() {
    theme_btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        var dark = body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
        localStorage.setItem("dark-mode", dark);
    });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem("dark-mode")) {
        toggle();
    }
});
```

Gracias por leer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La funcion toggle no debería agregar un event listener, directamente tendría que cambiar a modo oscuro

```
function toggle() {
    var dark = body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
    localStorage.setItem("dark-mode", dark);
}

theme_btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
     toggle()
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem("dark-mode")) {
        toggle();
    }
});
```

**EDIT**:

```
function toggle() {
    var dark = body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
    localStorage.setItem("dark-mode", !dark);
}
```

Comment: Oh, fallo mío. Gracias por la ayuda, sin embargo, ahora se me presenta otro problema. El código funciona y cada que recargo la página me agrega el tema oscuro, pero, ¿Y si la persona que está navegando prefiere no usarlo? Al recargar la página estaría obligado a usar el oscuro.

Comment: Por si no fui claro. Al abrir una pestaña nueva, el tema por defecto es el normal, al tocar el botón y recargar, se pone el oscuro. Hasta ahí todo perfecto. ¿Pero cómo hago si la persona prefiere no usar el modo oscuro y usar el que viene por defecto? ¿Cómo puedo revertirlo?

Comment: Intenta abrir tu app en una pestaña en incognito o otro navegador y decime cual es el color por defecto

Comment: Por defecto es blanco. Te paso la página web así lo compruebas, miras si quieres la clase y los estilos, junto con el código de js. Es funcional solo que si vuelvo a dar en el botón, me regresa al blanco, pero al refrescar me pone el negro.
https://priva.naivemedia.repl.co/

Comment: Creo que tu problema esta en el css, la clase darkmode en realidad lo esta poniendo en whitemode y otra observación es que en las clases de tu body el dark-mode esta por default te recomiendo fuertemente que arregles tu css por que en el futuro te vas a confundir mucho si quieres cambiar algo. mas allá de esto edite la respuesta con una posible solución sin tener que modificar el body ni el css

Comment: No funcionó como esperaba. Respecto a cómo está el css tiene una explicación, pero bueno, quizás deba modificarlo y ver si ahí se encuentra la razón. De todos modos, muchas gracias por la ayuda. Sirvió bastante.